# Timezone settings for WebSphere 6.1

Tags: time, application-server, settings, timezone

We have an application running on WebSphere which does (apart from other things) logging with timestamps.

These timestamps are GMT. We are in the CET Timezone (Germany).

WebSphere allows to specify in which Timezone you are, by way of specifying a custom property for the JVM: TZ=CET-1CEST-2,M3.5.0/02:00:00,M10.5.0/03:00:00 (just like in Unix).

The problem:
It only works kind of... Instead of GMT the timestamps seem to be GMT-1 (instead of 15:00 we have 14:00). So the Daylight Savings time is not accounted for, although it is specified in the Variable...

Anyone has an idea how to set that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, countless tries later:

The correct Answer is:

```
TZ=CET-1CEST
```

It seems that 3 Parts are necessary:

1. CET (Name of Standard Local time/Documentation gives a list of those)
2. -1 (Offset from UTC. "-" means to the east, not less in absolut time)
3. CEST (Name of a Daylight savings time scheme, without it no dst is used. This has to be an official value, I guess, 'cause fictional names just don't work, but IBM's documentation doesn't give those).

One letter more or less and it stops working. Guess IBM's documentation is just faulty.